# Proguard with Android gives me JNI error

Tags: android, android-ndk, proguard, android-proguard

After using ProGuard on Android application with some native (JNI, C++) code - application crashes in loading process. Message:

> *****               ***** Build fingerprint:
>   'Xiaomi/markw/markw:6.0.1/MMB29M/V8.2.4.0.MBEMIDL:user/release-keys'
>   Revision: '0' ABI: 'arm' pid: 15075, tid: 15115, name: Thread-10486
>
> > com.mynamespace.myapp <<< signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr -------- Abort message:
> >     'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION:
> >     use of deleted global reference 0xe5617166'
> >         r0 00000000  r1 00003b0b  r2 00000006  r3 de161978
> >         r4 de161980  r5 de161930  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
> >         r8 ab4446c8  r9 f52d7378  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
> >         ip 00000006  sp de1609f8  lr f7360f5d  pc f7363358  cpsr 40070010
>
> backtrace:
>       #00 pc 00044358  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
>       #01 pc 00041f59  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
>       #02 pc 0001ba6f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
>       #03 pc 00018c11  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
>       #04 pc 000167d0  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
>       #05 pc 00321145  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+212)
>       #06 pc 000f3cdd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2212)
>       #07 pc 0024f817  /system/lib/libart.so (*ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2*+1526)
>       #08 pc 0024fc21  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+68)
>       #09 pc 0033e107  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+686)
>       #10 pc 0031a031  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+248)
>       #11 pc 0028e30d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI10NewObjectVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+1064)
>       #12 pc 0010724f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI10NewObjectVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+866)
>       #13 pc 00093768  /data/app/com.mynamespace.myapp-1/lib/arm/librhodes.so

Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is "Use logcat with adb to catch normal log". This is the best way, I think.

> adb -e logcat > output.txt

Of course that was the problem with reflection api and renaming private methods.

Answer (score 0):

`---- Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted global reference 0xe5617166'`

You were using a deleted global reference as the parameter of NewObject.